# How to properly start nginx in Docker

Tags: nginx, docker, port, cloud-foundry

I want nginx in a Docker container to host a simple static hello world html website. I want to simply start it with "docker run imagename". In order to do that I added the run parameters to the Dockerfile. The reason I want to do that is that I would like to host the application on Cloud Foundry in a next step. Unfortunately I get the following error when doing it like this.

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["nginx -d -p 5000:5000"]
```

Error

```
Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:5000: unexpected error Permission denied.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From :: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

> EXPOSE does not make the ports of the container accessible to the host. To do that, you must use either the -p flag to publish a range of ports or the -P flag to publish all of the exposed ports. You can expose one port number and publish it externally under another number

CMD ["nginx -d -p 5000:5000"]
You add your dockerfile 
**FROM nginx:alpine**
its already starts nginx.
after you build from your dockerfile

you should use this on

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 <your_image>
```

Edit:
If you want to use docker port 80 -> machine port 5000

```
docker run -d -p 5000:80 <your_image>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that port 5000 was used by another application on my machine.